# $-(-v) = v$ for any $v \in V$

Tags: vector-spaces, solution-verification

This is a very simple fact to prove, but I am worried that my proof is so simple as to have no chance of being right.

> For a vector space $V$, $-(-v) = v$ for any $v \in V$.

**Proof.** Let $v \in V$. By the additive inverse axiom, 
$$v + (-v) = (-v) + v = 0,$$
so $v$ is the additive inverse of $-v$. Since the additive inverse in a vector space is unique, and we denote the a dditive inverse of $-v$ by $-(-v)$, we have
$$v = -(-v).$$

Have I skipped any steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof sounds good. As you have mentioned, the additive inverse is unique. To be rigorous, we are going to prove it next.

Indeed, consider a vector $v\in V$ and let us assume it admits two different additive inverses, which we shall denote by $w$ and $z$. Consequently, we have that
\begin{align*}
w = w + 0 = w + (v + z) = (w + v) + z = 0 + z = z 
\end{align*}
and we are done.

Based on such result, we conclude that
\begin{align*}
(-v) - (-v) = 0 = (-v) + v \Longrightarrow v = -(-v)
\end{align*}
as desired. Hopefully this helps.